# Post to Tumblr via email

Tags: tumblr

How do I post to Tumblr from email?

My login/account screen doesn't have the "Goodies" button at the top as shown in this help page for Tumblr:

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/email_publishing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To publish to your tumblr you can send an email to a private email address which can be found out by [following these steps](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/email_publishing):

> **How do I find my email address for mobile + email publishing?**
>
> 1. Click your blog's name at the top of your Dashboard or under the list icon at the top right.
> 2. Click "Blog settings" on the right side of the page.
> 3. You’ll find your private email address in the “Post by Email” section. (You can always reset this if you’re having issues publishing.)

The settings page has a URL looking like `http://www.tumblr.com/blog/<name>/settings`.

More information on post by email can be found in [the tumblr help](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/email_publishing).

Comment: Seems that this is no longer located on the Goodies page. Any idea where it went?

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller: Updated.

Comment: Awesome, I've been wondering where it disappeared to. Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, I couldn't find it through the menus, but this direct link: https://www.tumblr.com/settings/blog/ worked for me.